# R loop change variable names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Looked over several posts on this topic, but still couldn't figure out. Thought I'd just ask:

I wrote a for-loop:

```
for (i in 0:5) {
     est16_y2016$pov50_[i] <- est16_y2016$pop[i]*est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5
               }
```

to achieve the same results as the following code:

```
 est16_y2016$pov50_0 <- est16_y2016$pop0 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5
 est16_y2016$pov50_1 <- est16_y2016$pop1 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5
 est16_y2016$pov50_2 <- est16_y2016$pop2 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5 
 est16_y2016$pov50_3 <- est16_y2016$pop3 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5 
 est16_y2016$pov50_4 <- est16_y2016$pop4 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5 
 est16_y2016$pov50_5 <- est16_y2016$pop5 * est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5
```

But the loop doesn't work. No error message, no new variables generated either. Help! Thanks.

Comment: Try `paste0('est16_y2016$pov50_',i)`

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). What are you trying to do? Please provide a little more context.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm trying to generate some new variables (you probably can tell from my code), and I want to use for-loop to make the code more compact.

Comment: @A.Suliman where do I put it in the loop? Thanks.

Comment: If you do `i <- 0 ; est16_y2016$pov50_[i]` on the command line by itself, what do you get? Perhaps you mean `est16_y2016[[paste0("pov50_",i)]]`? Realize that the `$` operator is special and does not do the string concatenation that you are expecting here.

Comment: To generate new variables see `help("assign")`.

Comment: @EricWang Sorry, this should help `for (i in 0:5)  est16_y2016[,paste0('pov50_',i)] <- est16_y2016[,paste0('pop',i)]*est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5 }`

Comment: A `{` is missing.

Comment: @A.Suliman Thank you so much, it worked!!!

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks. But your answer is irrelevant here Because I'm asking about a loop, not ways to generate new variables. Even if I use `assign`, how could I use it in a loop.

Comment: @JohnColeman To be honest, I don't think it's an XY problem. Let me know what part of my question you don't understand?

Comment: I mentioned `assign` because as stated `est16_y2016$pov50_[i]` is not valid R code.

Comment: You seem to be trying to modify a dataframe by creating new variables in a loop. A more idiomatic way would be to create all the new columns at once and then use something like `cbind` to add them to the dataframe and then assign the variables names. Furthermore, there is probably a tidyverse approach that could do it all in a single line of code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I know it's not valid and that's exactly why I'm asking the question here. Simply switching to `assign` doesn't solve my problem. I appreciate your willingness to help tho.

Comment: OK, I will post a solution illustrating my comment to the answer by @GordonShumway. (It doesn't use `assign`, by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

Though the construct `data$column_name` is very convenient when in an interactive R session, when programming it may cause some problems. @A.Suliman's comment presents a way to solve those problems, here is another one.

```
for(i in 0:5){
    target <- paste("pov50", i, sep = "_")
    pop <- paste0("pop",i)
    est16_y2016[[target]] <- est16_y2016[[pop]]*est16_y2016[["ITPR_0.5"]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to answer your question without a reproducible example but I will give it a shot. `est16_y2016$pop[i]` will give you the `i`th element of est16_y2016$pop (which probably doesn't even exist. What you want instead is `est16_y2016[paste0("pop",i)]`
so you code should look like this:

```
for (i in 0:5) 
    {
     est16_y2016[[paste0("pov50_",i)]] <- est16_y2016[[paste0("pop",i)]]*est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5
     }
```

(edited)

Comment: Do the same with `paste0("pov50_",i)`. And this looks like a df, use double `[[` as in `est16_y2016[[paste0("pop",i)]]`. You should edit the answer.

Comment: GordonShumway, your assignment is wrong. The OP wants columns named `pov50_0`, `pov50_1`, etc. The suggestion to use `paste0("pop",i)` is for the lhs, not rhs.

Comment: Please see @A. Suliman 's answer above. Not all questions require a reproducible example.

Comment: @EricWang Yes they do, see the amount of comments, with a reproducible example it would all have been more clear to start with.

Comment: @RuiBarradas they do? We've already got a solution. Matter of fact, the very first comment by A.Suliman is a solution. It's funny that so many people who don't know the answer just keep commenting.

Comment: missed the lhs. wouldn't have happened if I'd had a reproducible example to work with.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to create a new variable name with paste(), and the problem is how to use the corresponding variable instead of the name of a variable.

```
  for (i in 0:5){ 
    # Create new variable names
    pov.name = paste0("est16_y2016$pov50_",i)
    pop.name = paste0("est16_y2016$pop",i)

    assign(pov.name,eval(parse(text = pop.name))*est16_y2016$ITPR_0.5)
    }
```

In this code,

`eval(parse(text = pop.name)` uses the string *"pop.name"* as a variable name

`assign(pov.name,value1)`creates a variable named *pov.name* and assigns value1 to *pov.name*

This way, you can get six new variables without using a dataframe.